# reduction operation across all dimensions but one

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a Boolean numpy array with multiple dimensions, e.g.,

```
import numpy

a = numpy.random.rand(7, 7, 3) < 0.1
```

I would now like to do an `all` operation across all dimension but the last to retrieve an array of size 3. This

```
all_small = [numpy.all(a[..., k]) for k in range(a.shape[-1])]
```

works but because of the Python loop is awfully slow if `a` is long in the last dimension.

Any hints on how to vectorize this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `axis` param. So, for a `3D` array to skip the last one, it would be -

```
a.all(axis=(0,1))
```

To handle ndarrays of generic number of dimensions and perform `numpy.all` operation along all axes but the specified one, the implementation would look something like this -

```
def numpy_all_except_one(a, axis=-1):
    axes = np.arange(a.ndim)
    axes = np.delete(axes, axis)
    return np.all(a, axis=tuple(axes))
```

Sample runs to test out all axes -

```
In [90]: a = numpy.random.rand(7, 7, 3) < 0.99

In [91]: a.all(axis=(0,1))
Out[91]: array([False, False,  True], dtype=bool)

In [92]: numpy_all_except_one(a) # By default skips last axis
Out[92]: array([False, False,  True], dtype=bool)

In [93]: a.all(axis=(0,2))
Out[93]: array([ True, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)

In [94]: numpy_all_except_one(a, axis=1)
Out[94]: array([ True, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)

In [95]: a.all(axis=(1,2))
Out[95]: array([False,  True,  True, False,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)

In [96]: numpy_all_except_one(a, axis=0)
Out[96]: array([False,  True,  True, False,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```